# generate layers for maps (Google or OpenLayers)

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, overlay, openlayers, layer

I'm trying to develop a software that gets data from a text file and generates a map layer. The map later on is going to be cut into tiles and used as overlay for Google Maps API or OpenLayers.

The data stored in the text file is weather data. The file has data about 1 x 1 squares. For example: there is .9 chance of rain for lat 1-2 and lon 5-6. I have to use the data provided in the data file and can't use pre-generated layers.

I generate the map by dividing a background white PNG into 360 horizontal boxes and 180 vertical ones and color each one based on the data available in the text file.

My problem is the fact that there are 180 latitudes and 360 longitudes but the base map for OpenLayers and Google Maps is a square. In other words, number of latitudes equals the number of longitudes in OpenLayers and Google Maps. Moreover when I take a world map and stretch it vertically the lines do not align at all.

Example:
OpenLayer base map (256px x 256px):
[image]

Generated layers (256px x 256px):
[image]

When I add the layer on top of the base map. Continents don't match. I don't have this problem when i use a non-square(256px x 128px) base map.
[image]

My question is how should I generate my layover so it works with a square world map that is being used by Google and OpenLayers?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to generate an image that is 360 x 180 pixels and use it as a base map in OpenLayers, ie, that the projection will be lat/lon (4326)? If so, you can, and there are a couple of inaccuracies in your question around this, which I will clear up, once I am sure what you are asking.

Comment: no I want to create an overlay (layer) that is going to be placed on top of the base map. [This page](http://openweathermap.org/tutorial/maps) has example of how I'm going to use the generated layer.

Comment: OpenLayers does not itself have a base map, though there is a standard one used in the examples. You can load any wms you like in any projection. The issue you are facing is due to different projections. By the OpenLayers basemap, I assume you are talking about spherical mercator, EPSG:3857, which is projected and in meters (and is also what Google Maps uses -- they invented it, after all). You will need to produce your weather data in this projection to match. The formula can be found here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator

Comment: Zoom out fully in this [example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/osm.html), and you will see that your assumption about OpenLayers maps being square is incorrect. You set the pixel bounds via the map div css, and you set the map bounds in the extents of the map constructor.